# Why do I get a type error when destructuring parameters?

Tags: typescript, next-auth

When I try to destructure the credentials parameter in the authorize function I get these two type errors:

Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Record<"email" | "password", string> | undefined'
Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Record<"email" | "password", string> | undefined'

```
...
providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "example@email.com" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },

      async authorize({ email, password }) { ... }
  ]
...
```

Why is that? Isn't credentials an object containing these two attributes? I even tried to create an interface for it and so on but then the function threw a type error.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w65PYW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Looks like it might be `undefined`  according to your error message, so it's warning you that destructuring `undefined` will not do what you want.  Can't answer any further than that without a reproducible example though